# Add custom linking-only target to Makefile.am

Tags: c++, gnu-make, libtool, makefile

Can't figure out the most proper and portable way of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have GNU Automake system configured for building a library (which gives both dynamic and static ones, that's correct). This library has dependencies on other projects, each one represented by one or several libraries (either static or dynamic). One of the dependencies is represented by a set (>50) of static archives (.a) and I want these archives to be linked statically to my lib. One would suggest using `--whole-archive` flags for that, but it doesn't work as it requires strict ordering of flags/library list which is broken by automake system once Makefile is generated. So now I'd like to specify a separate target where I link all ".a" libs of that project into one .a static archive and then use that to link against my lib. Is this possible to achieve?